# How to import shared libraries created with numba export using ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes, numba

I tried following this example

http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/pycc.html

to get a pre-compiled version of my code.

However I don't know how to load it. Here what I've tried so far:

test3.py:

```
from numba import export

def mult(a, b):
    return a * b

export('mult f8(f8, f8)')(mult)
```

In the command line:

```
pycc test3.py
```

in the ipython console:

```
import test3.so
# ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (inittest3)
# this seems to be expected according to the numba-doc, it suggests use of ctypes
import ctypes
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('test3.so')
# OSError: test3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This gives me an error....

I have a feeling this is my ignorance of how to use `ctypes` + `pycc` rather than a `numba` problem. Any help appreciated.

Comment: In the current directory use `lib = ctypes.CDLL('./test3.so')`. I'm not familiar with numba, but probably the function is exported as "mult" and takes two `double` args and returns a `double`, i.e. `lib.mult.argtypes = (ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double);` `lib.mult.restype = ctypes.c_double`. Call it as `result = lib.mult(a, b)`.

Comment: your god! how, what, where? do you think you could explain what just happened in a full answer or give me a link to relevant information?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes